# Reachability as linear map and energy ellipsoid

Tags: linear-transformations, linear-control

**EDIT:**

[In one of Steve Brunton's video lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNHx62HbKNA&list=PLMrJAkhIeNNR20Mz-VpzgfQs5zrYi085m&index=8) which I really like, he designs this [energy ellipsoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNjA7.png).

The description about it (as I perceive it), is that:
even if a system is not globally controllable, some controllable directions can be found using the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) of the Controllability Matrix, and be ordered from more to less controllable ones. The main axes of the ellipsoid are the singular vectors and the ellipsoid represents "**how far the system can reach along the controllable direction, in comparison to other less controllable directions**, **given the same input energy**".

Assuming though a controllable 3-dimension system, given a specific $B$,where following the SVD, we can order the controllable directions from more controllable to less controllable, e.g.:
[$ξ_1$ $ξ_2$ $ξ_3$], where $ξ_1$ is the most controllable while the $ξ_3$ is the least controllable.

What confuses me:

On the one hand, for a linear transformation R (reachability), R: U→X, where U is the domain and contains the inputs, and $X$ is the codomain and contains the final states, if I translate correctly the information from the energy ellipsoid, one $u(t)$ can be mapped in more than one value of ξ. How is this supposed to happen?

On the other hand, it does make sense that with the same input there can be more possible "final destinations". In that case however, both $ξ_1$ and $ξ_2$, as well as $ξ_3$, are all calculated by the same integral:
$$\int_0^t e^{A(t-τ)}Bu(τ)dτ$$
Shouldn't there be a factor to distinguish between the different vectors?

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here. Any advice?

Comment: What do $\xi_1$, $\xi_2$ and $\xi_3$ refer to? The eigenvectors of the (finite time) controllability Gramian? In that case you can just calculate the eigendecomposition of this controllability Gramian.

Comment: Perhaps, I am misinterpreting something, but what I actually wanted to know are the equations of the other two singular vectors (indeed the ξ are meant to be what you said). In other words, I have a system which is controllable, and therefore i know that all directions are reachable. This $u(t)$ is common and with it I can reach either 1 , 2 or 3. If I apply the u(t) to my system being at the initial state $x(t_0)$ which direction is my system going to follow, given that $B$ is also the same? It seems that 1 $u$ corresponds to more than 1 elements of the codomain

Comment: In general for some arbitrary input as a function of time $u(t)$ which satisfies some norm constraint (I believe this constraint would be $\int_0^t u(\tau)^\top u(\tau)\,d\tau=1$) the final state would be some point inside or on the ellipse.

Comment: Shouldn't one $u(t)$ be mapped to one $ξ(t)$? So that Reachability be one-to-one?

Comment: If Reachability is of dimensions $nxq$ and $u$ vectors are $qx1$, can one input vector be mapped onto anything else than a state of dimensions $nx1$?

Comment: The input $u(t)$ is a time varying function, so can be seen as infinite dimensional/degrees of freedom.

Comment: In the case of a "unit" input, therefore constant, which is the case used for the example in the lecture, how could the existence of three possible final states coincide with the R transformation being one-to-one?

Comment: Are you referring to the lecture cited in your question, because I didn't see the example with constant input. Are you maybe confusing $u(t)$, which used to denote any time varying input in this case, with the heavy sided step function, which is often also denoted with $u(t)$?

Comment: I surely need to specify the things you mentioned. You are right in that the way i put things has been confusing.
In the example presented in the lecture, what is mentioned is a "unit of input". The tutor uses as example, a car with a specific amount of gas, say 10 liters (unit of input, constant), and states that with this input, the car can go further in the direction $ξ_1$ which is considered as the most controllable, but also with the same amount of gas, if the driver chooses another direction, the car will not go as far, as before.

Comment: If the input remains the same, $B$ is either way the same, and grants us global controllability, and final time is also the same (the car is depleted from gas at the same time in each one of the cases, but in different distances), what changes in the integral that will distinguish the $ξ_1$ from the $ξ_2$, from the $ξ_3$?

Comment: A unit input does not have to imply a constant input. He actually also calls it a fixed amount of input energy, where this input energy is often defined as the integral from my previous comment, namely $$\int_0^t u(\tau)^\top u(\tau)\,d\tau.$$